# How does automatic username generation work for Facebook authenticated accounts?

Tags: discussion, support, users, privacy, facebook

I have just noticed a user with username `facebook-10000##########`. Usually when you create an account (or don't create one, depending on the site) you get some `user#######` username. Is this different for when you create an account using Facebook for authentication?

My main interest here is the following... I went to facebook.com/1000######### and got to a user profile. Given the sparse nature of the Facebook IDs, there being an actual account seems more than coincidence. Which then raises the question: *Is this odd username chosen by the user? Or is it generated by the system?*

So when it is generated by the system, it means that *the Stack Overflow account is visibly connected to some Facebook account* per default. I don't think that if this is the case, this is obvious to people and the behaviour that people expect and really want. At least for me, I would not want such a rather obvious connection to my Facebook profile.

I should have earlier come to think of the data explorer; It says that 691 had the same idea of a `facebook-###########` username... Is that likely? (Note that some have the same profile image here and there, so it is very likely their Facebook account they signed up with.)

Comment: They must have set their own name to that, on purpose. The auto names are never based on any of their other info.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: This seems really strange as it seems to be [quite hard](http://xenforo.com/help/facebook-user-id/) to find that information. But well, SO users have always been special ;) Its just that this user has probably just created his account to ask the question... I wonder if the data explorer allows us to enumerate past usernames...

Comment: @AndrewBarber: ok, I should have earlier come to think of the data explorer. It says that 691 had the same idea of a `facebook-###########` username... Is that likely? (note that some have the same profile image here and there, so it is very likely their facebook account they signed up with)

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I'm not sure what you mean by *sparse nature of Facebook IDs*; Facebook ID's are incremental. The only time an ID will not be found is if the account has been deleted.

Comment: @Matt: Take an abritrary ID and go through the next increments and you will find (at least the 500 times I did do it) that more often than not you will hit a "page not found".

Comment: @PlasmaHH: http://jsbin.com/lupagupe/1/. I got 420 profiles found out of 500. Note that the code in my bin will only work once, then the requests-per-IP for the API will be reached. I don't think accounts under the age of ~16, ~18 appear publicly, so that might be why you're getting so many errors if you're hitting the public site.

Comment: @Matt: Might have been different for the range I tried (1000#########  numbers). But anyways quite irrelevant for the question, as noted by my data explorer results...

Comment: I just added the info from your comment to the question; I think that could be significant information here.